# How can I view the data attributes value live in the chrome developers tool?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to see the values as I explore the DOM in the developers tool. And also if possible see what binded to the element javascript wise. Is this possible using some plug in or how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 16):

Data attributes can be seen on the element: http://cl.ly/0w3V2H311E21241J2j45

If you're using jQuerys `.data()`, it doesn't change the data attributes of the element, so you have to call `.data()` to get it see it. I am not aware of any plugins that allow you to view it in the DOM explorer.

Event listeners can be found to the right by clicking on the element. Scroll down to the bottom of the CSS rules and you will see a section called "Event Listeners": http://cl.ly/2f3c3z312c3D2w43321s

Comment: omg, this drove me insane for a couple hours when I wouldn't see the data attributes updated in dev tools. thanks for the info.

Comment: To see the .data() settings, select the element in the Elements window. That element is then identified by **$0**. Type in the console `$($0).data()`

Comment: In reference to the above comment, you might need `jQuery($0).data()`  instead - but this is what I needed ... I always wondered what the `$0` meant.

Comment: would someone please repost the screenshots to a different service, both have "exceeded its view limit".

Answer (score 12):

Sorry if you are limited to use only Chrome developer tools.

However for others who can use Firefox it may be useful to know that there is a great extension for Firebug: [FireQuery](http://firequery.binaryage.com/), which is doing exactly what you ask plus other nice things.

[image: firequery screenshot]